# Mass renaming custom report type field labels

Tags: apex, reporting, metadata, custom-report-type

One of the great things about custom report types is that you can renamed the field labels on the columns. This could be done if say you wanted a CSV export to have column headers that confirm to a naming standard other than your current salesforce field names. However, with great numbers of fields, comes great amounts of time renaming the field labels. Is there a way that I can perform a mass update to a custom report type to change the labels on a field. I do have a CSV that maps the Salesforce API name to the new Label, just not sure how to do it programmatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I can think of to do it is to edit the XML for Custom Report Type directly, and to change the labels in that. You can do it with Eclipse, etc.

Comment: Could you provide a link to a how to on that. I am familiar with eclipse, just not with editing metadata that much.